# Why does firebase data not load on html template in ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have been trying to retrieve data from database using ionic. The problem is the data is not displayed on my ionic page no matter what I try. I even tried from tutorials like:

- https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/building-a-ionic-firebase-app-step-by-step
- https://www.javatpoint.com/ionic-firebase (which turns up similar to what I have been doing)

just incase I was wrong or out of touch but still the same issue. After searching online for help without success, I reverted back to the original, and the problem is it just display a blank page and it doesn't give any errors.

For service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Location {
  id: string;
    title: string;
    area: number;
    location: string;
    description: Text;
    image: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  private snapshotChangesSubscription: any;
  public currentUser: any;
  private user:any;
  locations: Observable<Location[]>;
  locationsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Location>;

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ){
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(res => {
      if(res){
       this.user = res;
       console.log('User '+res.uid+' is logged in');
       this.locationsCollection = this.afs.collection<Location>
      //  ('people').doc(res.uid).collection('locations');
       (
         `people/${res.uid}/locations`,
         ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp')
       );

       this.locations = this.locationsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
         map(actions =>{
           return actions.map(a => {
            // console.log('User '+res.uid+' is still logged in');
             const data = a.payload.doc.data();
             const id = a.payload.doc.id;
             return { id, ...data };
           });
          })
       );
      }
      });
  }

  getLocations():Observable<Locations[]>{
      return this.locations;
  }
```

For component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FirebaseService, Location } from '../service/firebase.service';
import {AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-locations',
  templateUrl: './locations.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./locations.page.scss'],
})
export class LocationsPage implements OnInit {

  locations: Observable<Location[]>;
   locationsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Location>;

  constructor(
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.locations = this.firebaseService.getLocations();

  }
```

For template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Locations</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let location of  ( locations | async)">
        <ion-label>{{location.title}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I'm using ionic version 5.4.9

Comment: did  u try with `this.firebaseService.getLocations().subscribe(resp, error)` ? Maybe there as an error there, which isnt shown?

Comment: I tried that but all I got was error ```Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable```

Comment: So apparently I logged out and created a different account and it has worked well... what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to avoid such error again, I changed the function to load data from ngOnInit to ionViewWillEnter i.e instead of:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.locations = this.firebaseService.getLocations();

  }
```

on the components page I used:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.locations = this.firebaseService.getLocations();

  }
```